# Pushing records to stack in Data Structure

Tags: c++, data-structures

I was wondering if it's possible to use

```
int age = 21;
string name = "marc";
char gender = 'M';
std::stack stck;
stck.push (age,name,gender);
```

to a Stack.
All what I've seen only pushes one item to the stack.

Comment: Google: "OOP". Create a Person or whatever and use it.

Comment: Sure you can push a record into wherever. Just create the record as a class or struct and go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an object containing the information you want to push and push that object.

```
struct Person
{
    Person(int age, String name, char gender) : age(age), name(name), gender(gender) {}
    int age;
    String name;
    char gender;
};

Stack<Person> s;
s.push(Person(age, name, gender));
```

This is perfectly normal C++, and any C++ book is going to explain the details.

Answer (score 0):

To define arbitrary data records without creating your own `struct` or `class`, you can use [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

using PersonRecord = std::tuple<int,std::string,char>;

int main() {
    std::stack<PersonRecord> s;

    s.push(std::make_tuple(21,"Marc",'M'));
    s.push(std::make_tuple(25,"Maria",'F'));

}
```

See it working [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99f9adc3d0ffc696).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't specific about the question and for that I'm sorry.

Comment: @OwonubiJobSunday You weren't very specific. Either ways work fine as you see. You may create a custom struct/class for your record, or just use my generic proposal. Totally depends on your further requirements you didn't mention in your question.